# How to deploy rails app on godaddy server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I bought a godaddy server, I want to deploy my rails app on it using Apache + Passenger + Capistrano.

However, it seems I can't install passenger in my server.

After I connect to my server using ssh and type 'sudo gem install passenger', it says sudo is an unknown command..

So can anyone tell me how to deploy rails app on a godaddy server?...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Linux distribution you have installed on your machine, in order to log in as superuser you can try "sudo su" or simply "su".

Obviously you need to have the superuser password.

Answer (score 0):

By default Go Daddy servers have a user you set with a password.  To gain root access you will type:

```
su -
```

You will then enter the same password you logged in with originally.  By default the user and root passwords are the same.

Comment: Are you on a virtual dedicated or dedicated server or shared hosting?

Comment: did you manage to deploy your app in the end? if so can you help me?